# R - Omit NA when plotting only a subset of levels of x and using scale_fill_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, na, fill

I'm trying to make a boxplot with X being detections of 3 types of a certain bird genus(Vermivora): two species and hybrids of the two. There were also occasions when none of the 3 were detected, yielding a 4th level of X, "none", in addition to "gwwa" "bwwa" and "hybrid".

I only want to plot "gwwa" and "bwwa", and I want "gwwa" to be yellow and "bwwa" to be lightblue.

I can't generate a boxplot without either a third box "NA", and when I try to omit NA then there is still a third box "FALSE".

The recurring error message I receive when making attempts to avoid those two outcomes is this:

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3): fill

Here is what I've written:

---

```
library(tidyverse)
VERM <- read.csv("C:/1Zack/GWWA Map Stuff/GWWA_bySpecies.csv")
Vermivora <- factor(VERM$Species,levels(VERM$Species)[c(2,1)])
Road_Proximity <- VERM$RoadCount_2km

ggplot(data=VERM, mapping = aes(Vermivora, y=Road_Proximity, fill=Vermivora))+
geom_boxplot()+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("yellow", "lightblue"))
```

---

Sorry, this is my first post, and I can't figure out how to include a screenshot and I can't figure out how to put each line of my code on its own line without a full empty line between them.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you add data using `dput`  function (`dput(VERM)`)?

Comment: You can add blocks of code with single spacing by indenting each line 4 spaces. You can then use normal indentation after that.  There is a button on the toolbar to add images, or `ctrl-g`.

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing how your data looks like (since you didn't provide it) so I made up some `VERM` data.frame in the example below. The main idea is that you should filter for what values you need in `Vermivora` variable (column).

```
library(tidyverse)
# Some made up data
VERM <- data.frame(Vermivora = c("gwwa", "bwwa", "hybrid", NA),
                   Road_Proximity = sample(4*10))
```

I presume this is similar to what you got based on the description of your problem:

```
ggplot(VERM, aes(Vermivora, Road_Proximity, fill = Vermivora)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

---

**Solution with `dyplr`**

Filter for the values that you need in the variable Vermivora.

```
VERM %>%
  filter(Vermivora %in% c("gwwa", "bwwa")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Vermivora, y = Road_Proximity, fill = Vermivora)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gwwa" = "yellow", 
                               "bwwa" = "lightblue"))
```

[image]

If you need a certain order on the OX axis, then order the factor Vermivora.

```
VERM %>%
  filter(Vermivora %in% c("gwwa", "bwwa")) %>% 
  mutate(Vermivora = ordered(x = Vermivora, 
                             levels = c("gwwa", "bwwa"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Vermivora, y = Road_Proximity, fill = Vermivora)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gwwa" = "yellow", 
                               "bwwa" = "lightblue"))
```

[image]

---

**Solution with `data.table`**

Using the more concise syntax of `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr) # for piping with %>% (not only dyplr use it; 
# pipeline is a Unix trait not a dyplr trait)

setDT(VERM) # converts to data.table from data.frame

VERM[Vermivora %in% c("gwwa", "bwwa")] %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Vermivora, y = Road_Proximity, fill = Vermivora)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gwwa" = "yellow", 
                               "bwwa" = "lightblue"))

# If you need to order the factor Vermivora:
VERM[Vermivora %in% c("gwwa", "bwwa")] %>% 
  .[, Vermivora := ordered(x = Vermivora, levels = c("gwwa", "bwwa"))] %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Vermivora, y = Road_Proximity, fill = Vermivora)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gwwa" = "yellow", 
                               "bwwa" = "lightblue"))
```

---

Note that when addressing a question, is almost always needed to see some data related to your problem. You can try that by posting the output of one of the following lines:

```
dput(VERM) # the entire data
dput(head(VERM, 20)) # the first 20 rows
dput(VERM[sample(x = nrow(VERM), size = 20),]) # a sample of 20 rows
# Or make up some data like I did in the above example.
```